# При работе с метками получаю странную страницу

Tags: дефект, локализация, описание-метки

Если выбираю "Помогите нам изменить описание метки" или "Править"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выполняется переход на страницу с таким сообщением.

```
РЎР»РёС€РєРѕРј РјРЅРѕРіРѕ РІР°С€РёС… РїСЂР°РІРѕРє Р±С‹Р»Рѕ РѕС‚РєР»РѕРЅРµРЅРѕ.
```

Страница не меняется и при перезагрузке (F5)...

Comment: сюда бы скриншот добавить и чуть подробнее расписать шаги, и можно на MSE будет продвигать дефект

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, так вроде все описал... По поводу скрина - вот эта одна строка и больше ничего.

Comment: то есть, если исходный код страницы глянуть, там больше ничего нет?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, хотел сейчас глянуть `html` той страницы - а она открылась нормально и теперь разрешается редактировать метки. :) Видно нужно опять дождаться отклонений моих правок...

Comment: Похоже, нашел по теме вопрос на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87123/339911)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, сам инцидент понятен. Поправили бы еще и страничку...

Comment: @ksa хватит заниматься некропостингом на основном сайте

Answer (score 3):

Если поправить кодировку то выйдет:

> Слишком много ваших правок было отклонено

А раз это проблема кодировки то это, вероятно, какая-то внутренняя проблема